# While converting xml to xslt values are not mapping

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi i am new xslt transformation i am trying to convert following xml using xslt but i am not getting the value of title in the result xml.

```
Input Xml: 

   <exam:orderReq>

                  <exam:item>

                    <exam:title>r</exam:title>

                    </exam:item>

              </exam:orderReq>

Xslt: 

     <?xml version="1.0"?>

        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 

xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  

xmlns:exam="http://www.jboss.org/bpel/examples" 

xmlns:prod="http://www.jboss.org/bpel/examples/product">

            <xsl:template match="/">

             <prod:productOrderReq>

        <prod:product xmlns:prod="http://www.jboss.org/bpel/examples/product">

             <xsl:for-each select="exam:orderReq">

             <prod:name><xsl:value-of select="exam:title"/></prod:name>

                 </xsl:for-each>

        </prod:product>

              </prod:productOrderReq>

            </xsl:template> 

        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I got below result iin which i am not able get the value for the element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <prod:productOrderReq 

xmlns:prod="http://www.jboss.org/bpel/examples/product" 

xmlns:exam="http://www.jboss.org/bpel/examples">

           <prod:product>

              <prod:name />

           </prod:product>

        </prod:productOrderReq>
```

Comment: Could you improve the formatting of your question, by removing all the unnecessary blank lines in your code samples. More importantly, your input XML sample is missing a declaration for the `exam` namespace prefix. You should add that to your question too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
I got the solution while writing xslt i missed the for each tag for the item as shown below.

Previous xslt:


xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  

xmlns:exam="http://www.jboss.org/bpel/examples" 

xmlns:prod="http://www.jboss.org/bpel/examples/product">

            <xsl:template match="/">

             <prod:productOrderReq>

        <prod:product xmlns:prod="http://www.jboss.org/bpel/examples/product">

             <xsl:for-each select="exam:orderReq">

             <prod:name><xsl:value-of select="exam:title"/></prod:name>

                 </xsl:for-each>

        </prod:product>

              </prod:productOrderReq>

            </xsl:template> 

        </xsl:stylesheet>


Modified xslt:

 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  

xmlns:exam="http://www.jboss.org/bpel/examples" 

xmlns:prod="http://www.jboss.org/bpel/examples/product">

    <xsl:template match="/">

     <prod:productOrderReq>

     <xsl:for-each select="exam:orderReq" 

xmlns:exam="http://www.jboss.org/bpel/examples">

<prod:product>

     <xsl:for-each select="exam:item">

     <prod:name><xsl:value-of select="exam:title"/></prod:name>

         </xsl:for-each>

</prod:product>

</xsl:for-each>

      </prod:productOrderReq>

    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```